# Stable transfection

Tags: molecular-genetics

I need to achieve stable transfection of a pCI-Neo plasmid into the genome of a mouse embryo. The most common way to achieve stable transfection is through positive selection, however positive selection would not work with embryos. How can I ensure stable transfection of this plasmid in a mouse embryo without damaging the embryo? Would this plasmid integrate itself when the cell divided? I plan to use effectene as the transfection agent.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that specific plasmid, but if you need integration, I think you need some sort of transposon or to take advantage of homologous recombination.

Comment: You can use lentiviral transfection.

Comment: don't people use ES cells in culture first and transplant positive cells into blastocyst? and in ES cells, since it is culture, you can rely on *very* low efficient homologous recombination, but still select your cells by Neo resistance

Comment: Thank you all very much for your suggestions, I am looking into integrating my gene into a lentivirus (I can't believe I didn't think of that). I'm very glad I came here for suggestions. =) Thanks again.